# Oracle TRIGGER to set 'RESTRICTION' column on table 'LRESTRICTION' to 'YES' based on 'LAMOUNT' column of table 'LMEMBER'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Im trying to create a trigger on oracle sql that updates the 'RESTRICTION' column of 'LRESTRICTION' table to display 'YES' or 'NO' based on the value of 'LAMOUNT' column of 'LEMBER' table when 'LAMOUNT' = 5, I have tried a few other ways but I cant seem to understand how to actually set a trigger properly as there always seems to be errors. I am new to sql and having a hard time understanding triggers as the error messages are also confusing to me they dont seem to be as straight forward as in other languages. My question here is how can I create a trigger that does what Im trying to do or is it even possible?

My tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LMEMBER ( 
FNAME VARCHAR2(10), 
LNAME VARCHAR2(10), 
MTYPE VARCHAR2(7), 
IDNUM NUMBER(6) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
LAMOUNT NUMBER(2), 
LDURATION NUMBER(3)
);

CREATE TABLE LRESTRICTION(
ID_NUM NUMBER(6) REFERENCES LMEMBER(IDNUM),
RESTRICTION VARCHAR2(3)
);
```

-------##########------
And my trigger looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_RES
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON LMEMBER

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF: NEW.LAMOUNT:5
        UPDATE LRESTRICTION 
            INSERT INTO LRESTRICTION(RESTRICTION)VALUES('YES')
    END IF;          
END;
```

Error is get from this:

```
Errors: TRIGGER SET_RES
Line/Col: 2/20 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
   like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset

Line/Col: 2/20 PLS-00049: bad bind variable '5'
```

also tried more triggers with SET RESTRICTION = 'YES' instead of INSERT INTO LRESTRICTION(RESTRICTION)VALUES('YES') and also tried 'WHEN' and 'WHERE' clauses instead of IF but I cant seem to make it work

Comment: What error message are you getting? There is a `THEN` missing and there are some typos: `IF: NEW.LAMOUNT:5` => `IF :NEW.LAMOUNT = 5 THEN`. And it seems you haven't made your mind up whether you want an update or an insert.

Comment: I am rather confused when in comes to triggers one I tried before this was
```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SET_RES
AFTER INSERT ON LMEMBER

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    WHERE LAMOUNT == 5  
        UPDATE LRESTRICTION 
            SET RESTRICTION = 'YES'
              
END;
```
it was giving errors as well

Comment: Your original one is better. As mentioned´, your `IF` clause is faulty, but then, what do you want to do? Do you want to insert a new row or do you want to update a row?

Comment: I want to update, I tried insert since I was failing continuously with update as well

Comment: Your concept doesn't make sense, because table LRESTRICTION references table LMEMBER. This means if table LMEMBER doesn't contain a record with a certain IDNUM yet, the table LRESTRICTION can't contain such a record, too. So your trigger must go on the table LRESTRICTION instead of table LMEMBER or must go on update only, not on insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typos in your `IF` clause. And the syntax for an `UPDATE` is `UPDATE table SET column = <something> WHERE <some condition>`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER set_res
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON lmember
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF :new.lamount = 5 THEN
        UPDATE lrestriction 
        SET restriction = 'YES'
        WHERE id_num = :new.idnum;
    END IF;          
END;
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working, I tried after you mentioned about the typos earlier but as you mentioned along with the typos my update syntax was incorrect. Thank you again. 

Gonna do some more practice with triggers and sql in general since I can finally move forward from this problem

Comment: @user20709674 The trigger in this answer has a correct syntax and might work for updates on the lmember table, but not for inserts due to your incorrect concept of this trigger. See my comment above.

Comment: Whenever the table lrestriction should contain a record with a certain id_num, the table lmember must already contain such a record. Therefore, you can't do the update in this trigger in this situation. As said, the trigger must go on table lrestriction  or can only be executed when updating, not when inserting in table lmember.

Comment: Yep, Jonas is right. in some points Something about the whole concept is fishy. You may want to insert into lrestriction when there is no row for the idnum in that table yet. But why are there two tables at all? It seems the table lmember alone would suffice.

Comment: its part of a small group project but my group mates are very inactive and their contribution is minimum at best and as I am new to sql im trying to learn on the go through trial and error things like these i think goes best if you have discussions among each other but as mentioned their contribution over all is worse than minimal, but yes I am gonna make changes keeping both your suggestions in mind

Comment: Just adding to this: Usually we don't store redundantly what we can select from the data we already have. In your case it is very easy to select all "restriction" rows (with a mere `select * from lmember where lamount = 5`). If you want a restriction column for convenience, you could create a view (`create view v_member as select m.*, case when lamount = 5 then 'YES' else 'NO' end as restriction from lmember m;`). Or add a computed column. Avoid redundancy in a database.